# RegEnumValue error code 259

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I want do delete all the values of a specific key on the registry.
I'm using the following code:

```
    HKEY registryKey = NULL;
RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, TEXT("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\TypedPaths"), 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &registryKey);

LONG result = ERROR_SUCCESS;

for (int i = 0; result == ERROR_SUCCESS; i++) {
    TCHAR name[16383];
    DWORD chars = sizeof(name);

    result = RegEnumValue(registryKey, i, name, &chars, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    RegDeleteValue(registryKey, name);
}

RegCloseKey(registryKey);
```

There problem with this code is that will only delete me half of the keys and return the error code 259(ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS)

Comment: From [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724865(v=vs.85).aspx): While using `RegEnumValue`, an application should not call any registry functions that might change the key being queried. Basically, you are modifying the underlying data structure that you are currently enumerating.

Comment: Well, always passing 0 for the index would probably solve it :)

Comment: @HansPassant No, like the doc says, don't modify the key while enumerating it. The better option is to collect the value names in a local list first, then loop through the list deleting the values.

Comment: Passing 0 is not enumerating it, that is re-starting the enumeration.